# Why do the pictures lose their quality when adding to the ImageList?

Tags: delphi, imagelist

I'm trying to create an ImageList for my TrayIcon but the images are not showing as high quality. They are originally very clear but as soon as I put them on the ImageList at Design-Time they are deformed. I tried 16x16 in ICO and PNG formats.

Also, which format is preferred in ImageLists?

Please advise.

Comment: What version of Delphi? Can you post a picture so we can see the artifacts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, ensure that you have the correct size of the images you're inserting against your image list's width and height. I can't give you an advice about the image formats, but I would say it doesn't matter - if you'll use ICO or PNG the result should be the same. Since some newer version of Delphi (I'm using D2009) there's a property ColorDepth, which is set to cdDeviceDependent by default. You can try to change this property, but I hope the default setting choose the right color depth for the inserted images.